# Will the messages sent from a deleted Facebook account be deleted from Messenger?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I recently **deleted** (not deactivated) my Facebook Account.  I believe I have read that it takes 14 days for the account to be deleted providing it has not been accessed/re-opened.  If I am incorrect, someone please tell me.  My question is that my friends can still see my last message I sent in their messenger, however my profile is blank.  Will my messages ever be gone with the account being deleted?

Answer (score 1):

**No**, your message will always be there in your friends inbox until he/she deletes it. But your name will not reflect. There will be no name, means no one can say who has sent those messages.

And yes, you are right with your information about account deletion.

Answer (score -2):

somebody highjacked a friend of mine's Facebook account a few days ago. Her messages show up with her picture but instead of the actual past messages it say "Message Unavailable. This message is not available on this app."